# Windows domain full hostnames cannot be resolved resulting in intranet not working

Tags: windows, hostname, intranet

- the domain: is foo.bar.local
- full hostname is: bla.foo.bar.local
- short hostname is: bla
- I installed winbind.
- here is my smb.conf:

  name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
- here is my nsswitch.conf:

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4

when I try to ping full hostname, I get: "ping: unknown host"

when I ping short hostname it works and shows me

PING bla.foo.bar.local (10.11.20.135) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bla.foo.bar.local (10.11.20.135): icmp_req=1 ttl=62 time=49.7 ms

*notice that it manages to get the full hostname!? :S

now the only reason I need it is cuz I'm trying to reach intranet websites.
when I type short hostname "bla" in firefox address bar, it automatically changes it to the full hostname (which is good, right?!) but then it says:

Server not found
Firefox can't find the server at bla.foo.bar.local.

what am I doing wrong? it's driving me nutz.
so if you are wandering then yes, it is company intranet I'm trying to reach from ubuntu. If I use my crappy winxp everything is working perfectly well.

Comment: Do you have DNS enabled?

Comment: yes, DNS is enabled. I reach internet with no problems. only local intranet stuff doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it.
There are essentially 3 steps required to get Ubuntu to fully communicate with Windows based intranet machines.

1. Install Samba and Winbind
2. modify /etc/samba/smb.conf like this:

> [global]
>
> ```
>         workgroup = DOMAIN_NAME
>
>         server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
>
>    wins server = WINS_IP_ADDRESS
>
>         dns proxy = no
>
>    name resolve order = wins lmhosts host bcast
> ```

*notice the last line, "wins" comes first in the order!

1. modify /etc/nsswitch.conf instead of having:

> hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns wins mdns4

change it to:

```
hosts:          files dns wins mdns4
```

restart computer (or restart samba and network)
that's it, enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the first line of your resolv.conf file is:
search foo.bar.local

Comment: this is the content of my resolv.conf file:


# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search dhcp.inet.fi


I guess I'm not supposed to edit it ;)

Comment: I found out that I can do the same thing through the network manager but anyhow, it doesn't solve the problem, it actually made it worse so I can't ping other hostnames at all!